# Component-based system for JavaScript game

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, game, entity-component-system

I'm creating a JavaScript/WebGL based game and would like you all to take a look at the current entity component system which I created for it. I've used it once before on another project, and while I was very happy with the results, there were parts of it I did not feel 100% good about.

In particular, sometimes a component needs to call the `attachedEntities` version of a function it has overridden. For example `handleInput` might call the `attachedEntities` `handleInput` functions and then with the new `movementVector` multiply them by negative 1 so now all input while this component is active is reversed.

When I intercept the properties, I currently wrap intercepted function calls into a closure (see `basecomponent.intercept()`) so that the `this` object can refer to the component itself. Without that the `this` object was still being referred to as the `attachedEntity` (from within the components version of that function), so to get the components properties I had to run a query.

Things I've used as reference:

- http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/
- http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html
- http://blog.bengarney.com/2010/06/12/composition-vs-inheritance/

Full source code can be found [here](https://github.com/onedayitwillmake/ChuClone).

**Base Component**

```
(function() {
ChuClone.namespace("ChuClone.components");
ChuClone.components.BaseComponent = function() {
    this.interceptedProperties = {};
    return this;
};

ChuClone.components.BaseComponent.prototype = {
    /**
     * Array of properties intercepted, this is used when detaching the component
     * @type {Array}
     */
    interceptedProperties    : null,
    /**
     * @type {ChuClone.GameEntity}
     */
    attachedEntity            : null,
    /**
     * @type {Number}
     */
    detachTimeout            : 0,
    /**
     * Unique name for this component
     * @type {String}
     */
    displayName                : "BaseComponent",

    /**
     * If a component can stack, then it doesn't matter if it's already attached.
     * If it cannot stack, it is not applied if it's currently active.
     * For example, you can not be frozen after being frozen.
     * However you can be sped up multiple times.
     * @type {Boolean}
     */
    canStack                : false,

    /**
     * Attach the component to the host object
     * @param {ChuClone.GameEntity} anEntity
     */
    attach: function(anEntity) {
        this.attachedEntity = anEntity;
    },

    /**
     * Execute the component
     * For example if you needed to cause an animation to start when a character is 'unfrozen', this is when you would do it
     */
    execute: function() {

    },

    /**
     * Detaches a component from an 'attachedEntity' and restores the properties
     */
    detach: function() {
        clearTimeout(this.detachTimeout);
        this.restore();

        this.interceptedProperties = null;
        this.attachedEntity = null;
    },

    /**
     * Detach after N milliseconds, for example freeze component might call this to unfreeze
     * @param {Number} aDelay
     */
    detachAfterDelay: function(aDelay) {
        var that = this;
        this.detachTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            that.attachedEntity.removeComponentWithName(that.displayName);
        }, aDelay);
    },

    /**
     * Intercept properties from the entity we are attached to.
     * For example, if we intercept handleInput, then our own 'handleInput' function gets called.
     * We can reset all the properties by calling, this.restore();
     * @param {Array} arrayOfProperties
     */
    intercept: function(arrayOfProperties) {
        var len = arrayOfProperties.length;
        var that = this;
        while (len--) {
            var aKey = arrayOfProperties[len];
            this.interceptedProperties[aKey] = this.attachedEntity[aKey];

            // Wrap function calls in closure so that the 'this' object refers to the component, if not just overwrite
            if(this.attachedEntity[aKey] instanceof Function) {
                this.attachedEntity[aKey] = function(){
                    that[aKey].apply(that, arguments);
                }
            } else {
                this.attachedEntity[aKey] = this[aKey];
            }

        }
    },

    /**
     * Restores poperties that were intercepted that were intercepted.
     * Be sure to call this when removing the component!
     */
    restore: function() {
        for (var key in this.interceptedProperties) {
            if (this.interceptedProperties.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                this.attachedEntity[key] = this.interceptedProperties[key];
            }
        }
    }
}
 })();
```

**JumpComponent**

```
   (function(){
    ChuClone.namespace("ChuClone.components");

    ChuClone.components.JumpPadComponent = function() {
        ChuClone.components.JumpPadComponent.superclass.constructor.call(this);
        console.log(this)
    };

    ChuClone.components.JumpPadComponent.prototype = {
        displayName                     : "JumpPadComponent",                   // Unique string name for this Trait

        _textureSource                  : "assets/images/game/jumppad.png",
        _restitution                    : 2,
        _previousMaterial               : null,
        _previousRestitution            : 0,

        /**
         * @inheritDoc
         */
        attach: function(anEntity) {
            ChuClone.components.JumpPadComponent.superclass.attach.call(this, anEntity);

            var view = anEntity.getView();
            var body = anEntity.getBody();

            // Swap materials
            this._previousMaterial = view.materials[0];
            view.materials[0] = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
                color: 0xFFFFFF, shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
                map : THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( this._textureSource )
            });

            view.materials[0] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x608090, opacity: 0.5, wireframe: true } );

            // Swap restitution
            this.swapRestitution( body );


            // Listen for body change
            this.intercept(['setBody', 'height']);
        },

        /**
         * Sets the restitution level of  the provided body's fixtures to make it a jumppad
         * @param {Box2D.Dynamics.b2Body} aBody
         */
        swapRestitution: function( aBody ) {
            var node = aBody.GetFixtureList();
            while(node) {
                var fixture = node;
                node = fixture.GetNext();

                this._previousRestitution = fixture.GetRestitution();
                fixture.SetRestitution( this._restitution );
            }
        },

        /**
         * Set the body
         * @param {Box2D.Dynamics.b2Body} aBody
         */
        setBody: function( aBody ) {
            this.interceptedProperties.setBody.call(this.attachedEntity, aBody );
            if(aBody) // Sometimes setBody is called with null
                this.swapRestitution( aBody )
        },

        /**
         * Restore material and restitution
         */
        detach: function() {
            this.attachedEntity.getView().materials[0] = this._previousMaterial;

            var node = this.attachedEntity.getBody().GetFixtureList();
            while(node) {
                var fixture = node;
                node = fixture.GetNext();
                fixture.SetRestitution(this._previousRestitution);
            }

            ChuClone.components.JumpPadComponent.superclass.detach.call(this);
        }

    };

    ChuClone.extend( ChuClone.components.JumpPadComponent, ChuClone.components.BaseComponent );
})();
```

**Entity support for components**

```
    /**
     * Adds and attaches a component, to this entity
     * @param {ChuClone.components.BaseComponent}  aComponent
     * @return {ChuClone.components.BaseComponent}
     */
    addComponent: function(aComponent) {
        // Check if we already have this component, if we do - make sure the component allows stacking
        var existingVersionOfComponent = this.getComponentWithName(aComponent.displayName);
        if (existingVersionOfComponent && !existingVersionOfComponent.canStack) {
            return false;
        }

        // Remove existing version
        if (existingVersionOfComponent) {
            this.removeComponentWithName(aComponent.displayName);
        }


        this.components.push(aComponent);
        aComponent.attach(this);

        return aComponent;
    },

    /**
     * Convenience method that calls ChuClone.GameEntity.addComponent then calls execute on the newly created component
     * @param {ChuClone.components.BaseComponent}  aComponent
     * @return {ChuClone.components.BaseComponent}
     */
    addComponentAndExecute: function(aComponent) {
        var wasAdded = this.addComponent(aComponent);
        if (wasAdded) {
            aComponent.execute();
            return aComponent;
        }

        return null;
    },

    /**
     * Returns a component with a matching .displayName property
     * @param aComponentName
     */
    getComponentWithName: function(aComponentName) {
        var len = this.components.length;
        var component = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            if (this.components[i].displayName === aComponentName) {
                component = this.components[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        return component;
    },

    /**
     * Removes a component with a matching .displayName property
     * @param {String}  aComponentName
     */
    removeComponentWithName: function(aComponentName) {
        var len = this.components.length;
        var removedComponents = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            if (this.components[i].displayName === aComponentName) {
                removedComponents.push(this.components.splice(i, 1));
                break;
            }
        }

        // Detach removed components
        if (removedComponents) {
            i = removedComponents.length;
            while (i--) {
                removedComponents[i].detach();
            }
        }
    },

    /**
     * Removes all components contained in this entity
     */
    removeAllComponents: function() {
        var i = this.components.length;
        while (i--) {
            this.components[i].detach();
        }

        this.components = [];
    }
```

**Usage**

```
var jumpPadComponent = new ChuClone.components.JumpPadComponent();
entity.addComponentAndExecute( jumpPadComponent );

//... Some time later
entity.removeComponentWithName( ChuClone.components.JumpPadComponent.prototype.displayName );
```

I'm curious about others' thoughts on this implementation of such a component-based system for a JavaScript game.

`JumpPadComponent` attached to a couple of standard entities:

[image: JumpPad component toggle]

Comment: "i did not feel 100% about. <code dump>" Would you like to give a high level overview of which parts might need addressing

Comment: A rough review of the code makes me think it's far too verbose and over-engineered. KISS.

Comment: Well that isn't much help, in fact you had already posted that before I finished posting the entire code dump - specifically the management of components within the entity. Which was one of the more important parts ot it.

Answer (score 5):

Your code requires a ton of domain knowledge to properly review. I went to your Github repository to try and be more familiar with what you have.

**Entity support for components**

You asked specifically for this one, and I did find some things to ponder upon.

**`addComponent`**

- `existingVersionOfComponent` -> a better name could be `existingInstanceofComponent` or even simpler `instance`, as there is no versioning.
- `// Remove existing version`, for me it is confusing that the component can `stack`, but you still only allow 1 instance of it. Maybe you should find a better name/descriptor than `stack`.

**`addComponentAndExecute`**

- You return `null` here , not bad in itself, except that you return `false` in `addComponent`.  You might want to consider reviewing your code and standardizing on `false` or `null`.

**`removeComponentWithName`**

- This code confuses me.  It seems built with multiple instances of the same component in mind, but then it `breaks` out the `for` loop. It seems you could write this code with 1 loop.
- You can merge the 2 loops here in to 1 loop:

  ```
  removeComponentWithName: function(aComponentName) {
      var len = this.components.length;
      var removedComponents = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
          if (this.components[i].displayName === aComponentName) {
              removedComponents.push(this.components.splice(i, 1));
              break;
          }
      }

      // Detach removed components
      if (removedComponents) {
          i = removedComponents.length;
          while (i--) {
              removedComponents[i].detach();
          }
      }
  },
  ```

  can be

  ```
  removeComponentWithName: function(componentName) {
      var len = this.components.length,
          removedComponent;
      for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
          if (this.components[i].displayName === componentName) {
              removedComponent = this.components.splice(i, 1).pop();
              removedComponent.detach();
              break;
          }
      }
  },
  ```

Comment: Great feedback. The get component with name, uses the string, displayName property of a component - because it looks for instances of that type, instead of a specific component.

Comment: Right, it can be called by other components with no specific instance in mind. For example a slowdown component, will just get a component called 'speedup' by name and disable it. Not sure what your question is then, obviously

Comment: Removed that part.